# Why Is my Ajax Call Returning null on the First Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery typeahead control that I am using to display a list of available students. The list narrows down as the user types more letters. Currently, it returning null when the user types the first letter. I've been using JavaScript callback function to do this. I've been debugging it, but I have been able to figure out why it's returning null. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

The JavaScript file with the api call:

```
var api = (function (window, document, $, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var currentResult;
    var CallAPI = function (obj, callback) {
            if (typeof (callback) === 'function') {
                $.ajax({
                    url         : obj.url,
                    method      : obj.method,
                    dataType    : obj.dataType,
                    contentType : obj.contentType,
                    data        : obj.data,
                    cache       : false,
                    success     : function (result) {
                                  callback.call(this, result);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textState, errorThrown) {
                        return ('An error occur. ' + jqXHR.responseText);
                      }
                })
            }
        };

    var Service = function (obj) {
        CallAPI(obj, function (result) {
            currentResult = result;
        });
          return currentResult;
        }

        window.Service = Service;

        return {
            Service: Service
        }

})(window, document, jQuery);




var students = api.Service(obj);
console.log(students); //null when the first letter is typed. Then, it started to return more data.
```

Comment: You can not return from an asynchronous call

Comment: You make an asynchronous AJAX call and the data will be only available after the call has been finished. So if you are logging `students` before the AJAX call is finished it will be `null`. You can use `$.ajax({}).done( function () {} );` to execute something when the call has been finished.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls in javascript run asynchronously, so if you want to write code that relies on the data received back from the call, you have to wait for the call to complete. The only way to be sure of that is to put the code that reads the response into the callback function (or a function that is called by the callback function).

In your case that would be the "success" function defined in your $.ajax call, or the callback that it is currently set to run.